# How can I record the average time of a process in Anylogic?

Tags: java, time, anylogic

I am doing a medical-related simulation. As the picture shows, I want to record the average time people spent from timeMeasureStart to timeMeasureEnd. I only know how to make a simple Histogram distribution but how can I get the average time?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `TimeMeasureEnd` block has a build-in `DataSet` with all data. Use that to access the mean, mode, min, max, whatever you like. Simply use `myTimeMeasureEnd.dataset.` and access `getYMean()`:
[image]

Comment: As per Yashar: Do upvote responses that are helpful, this helps future users with similar issues to find these faster, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote and https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DataSet feature and access the mean with `dataset.getYMean()`.

Please see this link: https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/timemeasureend.html

Comment: Happy to help. Please don't forget to upvote if you find it useful.